# Looping through list and hide child li based on if statement

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, loops, each

I have a jquery mobile site that has a dynamic unordered list generated from a postgres and a while command in php.

After the page is ready how can I go through each list block and read the text thats in the **`span class="status"`** and if it is equal to 'D' then hide the related **`class='edit_btn'`** in the popup menu.

I gather this can be accomplished in jQuery?

Please see my example which will help explain my question.
http://jsfiddle.net/jamesil/wbcVy/1/

This is what I had done so far, but believe Im heading in the wrong direction

```
$('ul.bookings li').each(function() {
$(this).each(function(i) {
    var status = $('span.status',this).text();
    if (status = 'D') 
        $('ul.bookings ul li.edit_btn').hide();
});
```

Comment: the html in your fiddle is incorrect - you are closing your li before you add the div and buttons to it so your div with buttons is not part of the li with the status in it

Comment: Im aware of this. But its the only way I know how to do it in a while command, as I need the ul tag outside of the while statement and the div needs to be inside, but it works none the less.

Comment: it's still invalid html as you have a div as a child of a ul

Comment: Do you know how I can get around it? This is my php that generates the html in the link in my question.   http://jsfiddle.net/jamesil/hhsgp/

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/hhsgp/1/) would solve your invalid html problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix your invalid html problem as described in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/hhsgp/1/) you can use the following jQuery to hide your edit button:

```
$('#bookings li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('span.status').text() == 'D';
}).find('div').each(function() {
    //this is the bit where you need to find the id from the comment inserted by mobile jquery
    var divId = '#' + this.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '') + '-popup';
    $(divId).find('li.edit_btn').hide();
});
```

Please note that this will assume there is only one div in your li.  You may want to give that div a class so you can do a better selector on the find but I'm not sure if jQuery mobile will remove the class as it seems to have removed the original ID

If you are not able to change your html structure then just change the `.find` to `.next`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/wbcVy/3/)

Comment: Hi Pete,  Thats awesome, exactly what I wanted. Now im using the same script for different letters, but other letters are being returned with a space after the letter eg. 'D '  How can I tell your function to forget about the space after the letter?

Comment: @Jamesil just add `.trim()` - `$(this).find('span.status').text().trim()`

Comment: One last thing. I need another function like the one you wrote but instead of '.find('span.status').text().trim() == 'W';' can I include an IF statement? http://jsfiddle.net/jamesil/wbcVy/4/

Comment: sorry, I don't get what you are trying to do.  What is `wayTooLate` and where does it come from

Comment: Its a function that calculates what the current time is and if its within the next two hours then it needs to hide the two buttons buttons related to that booking.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. One last question, Ive taken your script and tried to make it work with that wayTooLate function, but it doesn't seem to be working. Could you check it out and see if I have written it wrong? I want to say if the returned statement is true, then hide the buttons. http://jsfiddle.net/wbcVy/6/

Comment: not sure if this works but this is how your function should look http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/wbcVy/7/

Comment: That makes sense, but Chrome is throwing up an error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined' for the line with 'var timeBits=' Do you know why?

Comment: it's because your first li doesn't have the span.date in it so you have to put in a check: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/wbcVy/8/